# get same row of information for celery task as celeryev or celerymon using simple python code

Tags: python, redis, celery, flask, gevent

I'm running celerly 2.5.1 with redis. I would like to obtain the same task information for a celery task that is displayed in celerymon or celeryev. That is:

celeryev 2.5.1
││  UUID                                 WORKER          TASK      TIME     STATE
││  59587fe7-b83f-4cf3-8343-6abdfbc016e7 watson-thinkpad app.task  18:14:03 RECEIVED

However, I see only two paths from the docs and various posts.

```
result = task.AsyncResult(task_id)
result.get()
```

which gets me whatever the task's callback returned, not the more informative row from celeryev.

And then there's the method used in celerymon which involves setting up a consumer, receiver, and separate thread to handle the information from celery in the context of a tornado process.

However, what I'm looking for is a simple call form like the former, but with the detailed information afforded by the latter. I don't need the information to be refreshed dynamically as it is in celeryev, just shown once.

Is there away to do this with the existing celery 2.5 API for python without spinning up a separate event loop or thread? I've got enough of those going already that I'd rather not have the additional complexity, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm in a somewhat similar boat, looking into different ways to get information back from celery tasks.